# Change Color a Textboxes from the Lower of the Highest

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 codes to change the color to Textbox, and unfortunately none of them work. What's wrong here? Why the code is not good. Every time I try the code, it tells me there are no variables. The first code changes the color to Textbox if there is a value between 1 and 7, and the second changes the value in ascending order from the lowest to the highest and assigns a corresponding color.

Images: http://www.imagebam.com/image/5ac5ee1073004874
http://www.imagebam.com/image/92a4091073004904

Code 1:

```
Public Class TextBoxColors
    Private ColorTable As Dictionary(Of String, Color) = New Dictionary(Of String, Color)()
    Public Sub New()
        ColorTable.Add("1", Color.Red)
        ColorTable.Add("2", Color.Aqua)
        ColorTable.Add("3", Color.Chocolate)
        ColorTable.Add("4", Color.BlanchedAlmond)
        ColorTable.Add("5", Color.BurlyWood)
        ColorTable.Add("6", Color.BlueViolet)
        ColorTable.Add("7", Color.DarkBlue)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetColor(ColorMap As String) As Color
        Return If(ColorTable.Keys.Contains(ColorMap), ColorTable(ColorMap), Color.White)
    End Function
End Class

Private txtColor As TextBoxColors = New TextBoxColors()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each txtDraw As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(txt) txt.Name.StartsWith("txtDraw"))
        AddHandler txtDraw.TextChanged,
            Sub()
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDraw.Text) Then
                    txtDraw.BackColor = txtColor.GetColor(txtDraw.Text)
                End If
            End Sub
    Next
End Sub
```

Code 2: This 2nd code must be changed based on my text box, which starts with SumtxtDraw

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     FillColorList()
 End Sub

Private Sub ColorTextBoxes()
    FillTextBoxList(16, 23)
    Dim SortedList As List(Of TextBox) = SortList()
    Dim index As Integer
    For Each txt As TextBox In SortedList
         txt.BackColor = lstColor(index)
         index += 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FillColorList()
    lstColor.Add(Color.Red) 'for lowest number
    lstColor.Add(Color.BlanchedAlmond)
    lstColor.Add(Color.PaleGreen)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Chartreuse)
    lstColor.Add(Color.CadetBlue)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Orange)
    lstColor.Add(Color.DarkMagenta)
    lstColor.Add(Color.Violet) 'for highest number
End Sub

Private Sub FillTextBoxList(StartNumber As Integer, EndNumber As Integer)
    lstTextBox.Clear()
    For suffix = StartNumber To EndNumber
        lstTextBox.Add(DirectCast(Controls("TextBox" & suffix.ToString), TextBox))
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SortList() As List(Of TextBox)
    Dim orderedList = From txt In lstTextBox Order By CInt(txt.Text) Descending Select txt '$"{scorer.Score} - {scorer.Name}"
    Dim SortedList As List(Of TextBox) = orderedList.ToList
    Return SortedList
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ColorTextBoxes()
End Sub
```

Comment: *"it tells me there are no variables"*.  No it doesn't.  It gives you a specific error message at a specific location.  Tell us what those two things are.

Comment: Try reading this link, it maybe similar to your question. [TEXTBOX COLOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134227/vb-net-class-to-change-textbox-backcolor-dynamically)

Comment: try moving the code in your Form.Load event to a method that handles your Form.Shown event. Sometimes code that changes the UI doesnt work as expected because the forms and their controls haven't been displayed yet,

Comment: This is my answer to a question from @Angga Sillvert. Add `Private lstColor As New List(Of Color)` and 
 `Private lstTextBox As New List(Of TextBox)` as class level (form level) declarations.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921449/compare-value-multiple-textbox-vb-net/53925520#53925520 for updated code.